# Spray - deserializing optional query parameter

Tags: scala, spray, spray-routing

From *spray.io* documentation page:

> `color`
>   extract value of parameter “color” as String
>
> `color.?`
>   extract optional value of parameter “color” as Option[String]
>
> `amount.as[Int]`
>   extract value of parameter “amount” as Int, you need a matching Deserializer in scope for that to work (see also Unmarshalling)

So how can I parse optional `Int` value? Something like `amount.?.as[Int]` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `"amount".as[Int]?` (see https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Parameter-Filters)?

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks. You can extract it to an answer, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the details here: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/76ab89c25ce6d4ff2c4b286efcc92ee02ced6eff/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/directives/NameReceptacle.scala

```scala
case class NameReceptacle[A](name: String) {
  def as[B] = NameReceptacle[B](name)
  def as[B](deserializer: FSOD[B]) = NameDeserializerReceptacle(name, deserializer)
  def ? = as[Option[A]]
  def ?[B](default: B) = NameDefaultReceptacle(name, default)
  def ![B](requiredValue: B) = RequiredValueReceptacle(name, requiredValue)
}
```

The straightforward syntax would be

```scala
"amount".as[Option[Int]]
```

Unfortunately there is no syntactic sugar to create a `NameRecaptable` for an option type directly, but you can do it in two steps:

```scala
"amount".as[Int].as[Option[Int]]
```

`?` is an alias for `NameRecaptable[A].as[Option[A]]`, so you can use the following code (note the postfix operator syntax):

```scala
"amount".as[Int]?
```